# Using variable to specify field in find?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the field name in a `find` by passing in a variable.  So instead of doing:

```
db.myCollection.find({fieldName = 123})
```

doing something like this:

```
var myVar = "fieldName";
db.myCollection.find({myVar: 123})
```

I get that this is a weird thing to do, but i'd like to know if this can be done and if so - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - just create an object and pass it in:

```
var myVar = "fieldName";
var params = {};
params[myVar] = 123;
db.myCollection.find(params)
```